# iOS: Add noise to backgrounds at runtime

Tags: ios, background, noise

A common styling trick to provide for more organic-looking surfaces (or to make gradients smoother) is to add noise, like in the right picture below:

[image: Plain]
[image: Added noise]

A good example of noise applied in iOS interfaces can be seen here: http://dribbble.com/system/users/1164/screenshots/173316/tp_chatview.png?1309741355

My question: Is there a runtime way to add noise to images in iOS (i.e. not using pre generated noise tiles)?

Comment: Using Core Graphics only, or is OpenGL OK?

Comment: i am searching for a core graphics way. if it's not possible without opengl, i'd rather use pre-generated noise tiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at this image filter project. 
https://github.com/samuelsoe/ios-image-filters

Here's the exact commit where noise filters were added. Should point you in the right direction.

https://github.com/samuelsoe/ios-image-filters/commit/13c40fce523a2ea6dcefdd3e9aa247aa4a1042ca

Answer (score 3):

An easier way is to use the following [class extension (categories)](https://github.com/jasonmorrissey/JMNoise) for UIView, its the best so far for such operations.

Import the .h file

```
#import "UIView+JMNoise.h"
```

then simply call applyNoise on the view

```
[self.view applyNoise];
```

Hope this helps